# Difference about AdSense and Ad Exchange

Tags: ads

What is the difference between AdSense and Ad Exchange?
From what I know Ad Exchange is like a net of advertisers. Can I use my AdSense account to show adversitements from the Ad Exchange platform?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a few words, Google Adsense is for editors, since Google Ad Exchange is for advertisers.

Google Adsense is a platform for web editors for including ads, provided by Google. Editors get some income just for including this content.

The content Google shows on these ads comes from Google AdWords, which is another platform that establishes the rules to make an eligible ad.

Google Ad Exchange is a dynamic marketplace for advertisers who want their ads to be published all around the web. They make an ad according to Google AdWords rules, they pay for influence and so their ads get automatically promoted through Google Adsense net.

So, answering your final question, if you are an editor with Google AdSense ads in your website; you are already displaying Google Ad Exchange ads.

Comment: So that means when I use AdSense in my web page the ads can also show advertisements from other providers than Google (that belongs to Ad Exchange network) ???

Comment: As long as I know, yes. But you cannot select exactly which ads to show. Google does this for you, according to your preferences, banned ads and, of course, strengthness (money) of the particular campaigns. Maybe you could get some further help from Google staff on the official AdSense forum: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense

Comment: google explains it here

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//adexchange/AdExchangeOverview.pdf